# Reading text from files and run it as code

Tags: c++, file-io

Reading texts from files in C++ is kinda simple. But what if I want to read text from files that I would like to run as code?

I'm working on a game and I realized that describing the coordinates and similar properties of those objects that are the part of each level takes very long space. I want to store it in text files, not in the code, because that'd be incredibly long after as the number of levels is increasing

I want to read the text and run it if it would be the part of the code. How to do it?

Comment: You mean your levels are made up of C++ code?

Comment: I would think you could use an XML integration library for this, it seems like you want something like a config file for each weapon. That being said you could write your own plain text one if you wanted to parse a file and then wire up the objects with the contained data.

Comment: Pubby: yes, I want everything in C++, or at least, in C.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt well, I'll suggest putting each level in a different file and `#include` them.

Comment: It sounds good, but when I do it, I got     error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create some kind of [domain-specific language (DSL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language), and write your game levels using that.

Another option would be to use a scripting language that can be embedded in C++, such as [Lua](http://www.lua.org/)  ([embedding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11508/Integrating-Lua-into-C)) or [Python](http://www.python.org/) ([embedding](http://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python/EmbeddingPython)).

**EDIT**

If you really want to do everything in C++, you could write each level as a different file (level1.h, level2.h, ...), each with its own namespace (level1, etc.) and include them all in "levels.h", which you include from main.

I imagine you could even do some template programming tricks so you could access them like:

```
for (const unsigned int level_num, levels)
{
    Level<level_num>::load() ;
}
```

The problem with this approach is that you lose a lot of flexibility. Every time you change your game levels, you need to recompile (and redistribute) your program.

An extreme (and not recommended) solution would be to distribute the CPP files as text, and compile them on the fly to DLLs, which you then load... ::shiver::

Comment: I want everything in C++, or at least, in C. If the method I thought doesn't work, then are there any other way to add values of each objects? If I'd do it in the "main()" function for each levels, it'd take thousands of lines, and that would be chaotic. I think this is fairly obvious.

Comment: @ZoltánSchmidt: You're probably still a beginner. Most code lives outside of `main`. In this case, you might have a separate `level1.cpp` file with the full level defintion, a `level1.h` that just lists the objects without the initialization details, and before `main()` just `#include "allLevels.h"`.